# lambdaで「from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials」を設定してもRuntime.ImportModuleErrorが発生する。

Tags: google-api, oauth

lambdaで作ったファイルをGoogledriveにアップロードする際、使用するgoogle apiを使用する認証に使うoauth2client.service_account のパッケージを読み込めずエラーが発生します。

この対策としてローカルで以下のコマンドでパッケージ作成し
pip install --target ./oauth2client oauth2client

zip化し、lambdaのレイヤーとして保存しそのレイヤーを読み込ませていますが、同じエラーが発生します。

他の解決策が現在見つかっておりません。
このエラー解消に他に試せることはあるでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ローカルで作成したパケジにて解決

pipパッケージをアップグレードして、ひとまとめにしたパッケージを作ることでエラー解決

pythonパッケージ
pip install --upgrade pip --target ./python requests google-api-python-client google-auth requests-oauthlib oauth2client